# Can't use curl inside a docker container that has installed it before

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, restheart

I'm using RestHeart docker image.

From it's [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/softinstigate/restheart/dockerfile/):

```
FROM openjdk:8u111-jre-alpine

RUN apk upgrade --update && apk add --update libstdc++ curl ca-certificates bash

...
```

This means that curl is currently installed, right?

I run that image inside a Docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.0
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  restheart:
    image: softinstigate/restheart:3.10.0
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
    volumes:
      - ./restheart:/opt/restheart/etc:ro
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

The container id for restheart container is `e1a023d9a8a9`.

But when I execute `docker exec e1a023d9a8a9 curl` I get:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"curl\": executable file not found in
>   $PATH": unknown

Comment: try `docker exec e1a023d9a8a9 bash -c curl`

Comment: I got: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: oh yes, it's alpine. then `/bin/sh -c curl` it should be

Comment: Again: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Comment: You can try my compose if you want, is simple as that.

Comment: Couldn't try your compose file as I need your restheart config files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Dockerfile is obsolete and I don't know why Docker Hub is still publishing that one, it's at least two years old!

The latest one is at https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/blob/master/core/Dockerfile

It's for RESTHeart v5

As the base image is gcr.io/distroless/java:11 then it does not contain even the sh shell.

By the way, if someone could tell me how to update that Dockerfile that would be very helpful, I can't find any link in the Docker Hub dashboard.

---

## UPDATE (24th may 2020)

Starting from RESTHeart 5.0.1 we have decide to move the Docker base image to `adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot-bionic`. See the new [Dockerfile](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/blob/master/core/Dockerfile).

Both the [latest](https://hub.docker.com/layers/softinstigate/restheart/latest/images/sha256-a2a940e83d40865cf7a9780f7dee6d4f28bb711499ff8a101b1e38fa582eccce?context=repo) and [5.0.1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/softinstigate/restheart/5.0.1/images/sha256-a2a940e83d40865cf7a9780f7dee6d4f28bb711499ff8a101b1e38fa582eccce?context=repo) tags of `softinstigate/restheart` images are now based on the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS distribution.

The distroless image is still built (see [distroless.Dockerfile](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/blob/master/core/distroless.Dockerfile)) and uploaded to Docker Hub, but it is tagged as `distroless` and `5.0.1-distroless` to distinguish it from the default image.

Release notes:
https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/releases/tag/5.0.1

Docker hub:
https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/softinstigate/restheart

Comment: I fixed downgrading to 3.9.0, in fact 3.1.0 was the first version of the distroless. I hope some image for developing is released, with at least bash. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed restheart is using `distroless` in their latest images. But I couldn't figure out why it's not allowing to `exec` in older images which are using alpine.
Even no luck with entrypoint overriding.

```
    $ docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash softinstigate/restheart:3.10.0 -c curl
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

But I built locally and it works.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart.git
$ git checkout tags/4.0.0
```

The tag `3.10.0` is not available at the repo.

```
$ cd restheart/Docker
```

Add [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/softinstigate/restheart/dockerfile/)

```
$ docker build --build-arg RELEASE=3.10.0 -t harik8/restheart:latest .
$ docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash harik8/restheart:latest -c curl
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```